# Upload file(Any Format) into Postgresql database using Python

Tags: python, database, postgresql, file-upload, psycopg2

I would like to upload a file to a postgresql database under a specific path. I have tried to search for it, but could not find much information on this topic. Just to clarify myself, I do not want to copy data into some table, instead I just want to upload a file to database. (just like we do a normal copy a file from local machine to server path).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Regards,
Manish

Comment: Even if it were possible, the file would have no *meaning* for the DBMS. What should it do with a JPEG file? How should it query it?

Comment: See [How to insert (file) data into a PostgreSQL bytea column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1742/38456)

Comment: Actually, the scenario is like this, every time I run a testcase it will create a measurement file and logging file and it will be automatically stored to a database, but there is another measurement file created by the testcase, which is stored on local disk. So, I want to attach this file to other generated files. But since they are in a database, I somehow need to attach it to the database.